# Python 3.4 -> Connect to PostGres SQL using SQLAlchemy win32

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2, python-2.x

I am using Postgres and Pandas and having trouble with connecting the two.
I have created the enginestr using SQLAlchemy as below

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/bilal')
```

However, when i run that statement i get the following error

```
ImportError : No module names 'psycopg2'
```

I have tried installing the module but dont have any luck. Is it because i am using a 32 bit Windows machine ?

Thanks,

Bilal

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from those two lines you posted, and not from where you're referencing `psycopg2`?

Comment: I wasnt successful in install psycopg2

Comment: Then you should be asking "How do I install psycopg2 on Windows 32bit?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install it correctly?
Use this link to download and install it [win-psycopg](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/) or using `pip install psycopg2`

And you could specify it in the connection string:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:password@localhost/bilal')
```

Comment: Just ran the above and got this

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:password@localhost/bilal')


ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2'

pip didnt install the module. Anaconda only shows it available for win64

Comment: try the first link it for win specifically, the error says your psycopg2 is not installed, that's why it can't be imported

Comment: download it from here http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/2.6.1/psycopg2-2.6.1.win32-py3.4-pg9.4.4-release.exe

Comment: do you have a link for python 3.4 / 3.5 ?

Comment: i gave it to you twice, check above

Comment: Thanks got it. Seems to be a problem with my iPython running v3.5. However, psycopg2 works in Python 3.4